# Add PHPExcel_IOFactory to symfony project

Tags: mysql, symfony, phpexcel

I want to use php script to import data from excel file to mysql data base

I found this turorial [Here](http://www.discussdesk.com/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-PHP.htm) which is so clear but in my case I use symfony framework and I don't know how can I include phpExcel_IOFactory .
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

will take care of installing and loading the classes.  After that, just use something like:

```
$reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$wb = $reader->load($filename);
$ws = $wb->getSheet(0);
```

Note the forward slash in front of the class name.

Comment: Thanks for your response ..It's ok now ..I should add **slaxh** in front of the class name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple you have to add `phpoffice/phpexcel` in your vendors. run:

`php composer.phar require phpoffice/phpexcel`

And that's all.

Comment: Thanks @metfan for your response I ve already add phpoffice/phpexcel whith composer but as Cerad said in his unswer I have to add slash in front of the class name.